# Sequence regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, sequence

I have sequence data with the following properties.

1) Very less or no repetitions of elements in a sequence

2) The length of each sequence is constant

3) The length of each sequence is far greater than the total number of sequences.

Let's say following are the sequences.

**Input sequences:**

```
A_input=np.array([1799, 2156, 2087, 1454,  515,  199, 1011, 3467, 4210, 3361, 2024,
       4641,  497, 3845, 4136, 2978, 1371, 1953, 3611, 1349])

B_input=np.array([1350, 1129, 3681, 4487,  637, 1285, 3412, 1277,  892, 2009, 4401,
       1329, 4300,  866, 2201, 3275, 4513,  346, 3164, 1262])

C_input=np.array([ 739,   77, 4818, 2759,   70,  121,  273, 1915,  103, 2983, 3709,
       3354, 2856, 3391, 3379, 2593, 3924, 1768, 2650, 2721])

D_input=np.array([1845, 4673, 1419, 1323,  736, 4912, 2104, 2055, 3844, 3219, 2611,
       1869, 1369, 1946, 3559, 1445, 3660,  554, 1579,  467])

E_input=np.array([1646, 4461,  944,  211, 3552, 3107, 4602, 3934, 4381, 4959, 4595,
       4040, 4834, 2593, 1558, 2760, 1303,  824, 2856,  976])
```

**Output regression:**

```
A_output=0.4
B_output=0.8
C_output=0.1
D_output=0.2
E_output=0.3
```

I tried to used few methods like [SGT](https://towardsdatascience.com/sequence-embedding-for-clustering-and-classification-f816a66373fb) but most of them works for sequences with repetitions in it?

Is there any method in `python` to train and predict the regression output values of the input sequences of the specific properties discussed above?

Comment: What are you showing us in the output? How does this work? What is the goal here?

Comment: sequence regression. Predicting the output for each sequence. Instead of features, I have sequences for regression.